# Rails Testing, multiple tests

Tags: testing, rspec

I was reading this blog post:

http://clarkware.com/blog/2007/09/08/how-would-you-test-this

and saw this code at the end:

```
describe MenuItemsController, 'Creating a new menu item' do

  before do
    @attributes = {'name' => "Enchilada", 'price' => 4.99}
    @menu_item = mock_model(MenuItem)
    MenuItem.should_receive(:new).with(@attributes).once.
      and_return(@menu_item)
  end

  it 'should redirect to index with a notice on successful save' do
    @menu_item.should_receive(:save).with().once.and_return(true)

    post :create, :menu_item => @attributes

    assigns[:menu_item].should be(@menu_item)
    flash[:notice].should_not be(nil)    
    response.should redirect_to(menu_items_url)
  end

  it 'should re-render new template on failed save' do
    @menu_item.should_receive(:save).with().once.and_return(false)

    post :create, :menu_item => @attributes

    assigns[:menu_item].should be(@menu_item)
    flash[:notice].should be(nil)    
    response.should be_success
    response.should render_template('new')
  end

end
```

I was under the impression that it was best to put each test (should, assert, expect) in it's own 'it' block.  This code puts several.

Yes, it makes the code easier to read but if for example the line: `flash[:notice].should_not be(nil)` failed then your results wouldn't point directly to that test would it?

What's the recommendation here? Each test individually or bundle some up to aid in readablity?

Neil

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general the best way is put just one assertion per test description, but it's still in discussion, as seen here: http://betterspecs.org/#single

For some cases I agree that many `expect`s at the same test could be useful, but, for instance, if the first `expect` fail then rspec will stop running that test and just say that this one failed.